# Word or phrase for things that are only noticed when they break? (or are pointed out)

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, programming

E.g. the engineering that goes into the roads we travel on, the railways we use, the negative space in a painting, or any of the many systems that we depend on.

Comment: The things we take for granted are *assumptions*.

Comment: Isn't that "invisible technology" as at https://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/columnist/2017/07/04/future-of-consumer-tech-all-about-timing/443220001/

Comment: "the bones" of it

Comment: 'You never miss the water till the well runs dry' aptly describes the situation (but not, directly, the everyday essentials we take for granted).

Answer (score 1):

**invisible** (adj.)

> Not noticed or acknowledged : treated as if invisible : overlooked
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invisible)

> If you say that you feel **invisible**, you are complaining that you are
> being ignored by other people. If you say that a particular problem or
> situation is **invisible**, you are complaining that it is not being
> considered or dealt with.
>
> *It was strange, how **invisible** a clerk could feel.*
> *The problems of the poor are largely **invisible**.*
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/invisible)

I don't see an entry in the OED online for this figurative sense. *The New Oxford American Dictionary* comes closer, but is still limited:

> *Figurative*  (of a person) treated as if unable to be seen; ignored or not taken into consideration: *before 1971, women artists were pretty well
> invisible.*

---

> In many places, infrastructures remain **invisible until they break
> down**...
> [Zlatan Krajina and Deborah Stevenson (eds.); *The Routledge
> Companion to Urban Media and Communication*](https://books.google.com/books?id=E0uxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT473&dq=invisible%20until%20it%20breaks&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi81dOr8ciDAxXLGFkFHSe1B-0Q6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=invisible%20until%20it%20breaks&f=false) (2019)

> A growing body of work has begun to move analyses of technological
> failure beyond the "**invisible until breakdown**" and
> "failure-as-event" paradigms.
> [Adriana Mica, Mikołaj Pawlak et al.
> (eds.) *Routledge International Handbook of Failure*](https://books.google.com/books?id=x8GnEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT312&dq=invisible%20until%20%20break%20down&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_09_Q8siDAxU0F1kFHZcRA54Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=invisible%20until%20%20break%20down&f=false) (2015)

> The same broad principle  has been taken up in more recent work in new
> media and technology studies, for example, Bowker and Star's (1999)
> observation that technologies and practices which rise (or sink) to
> the level of infrastructure are frequently **invisible until
> breakdown**, and ...
> [Tarleton Gillespie, Pablo J. Boczkowski et al.
> (eds.) *Media Technologies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3w23AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA230&dq=invisible%20until%20%20break%20down&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_09_Q8siDAxU0F1kFHZcRA54Q6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=invisible%20until%20%20break%20down&f=false) (2014)

> Infrastructures of modernity are often **invisible until they fail**.
> [Claudia Aradau and Tobias Blanke; *Algorithmic Reason*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2ZVsEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&dq=invisible%20until%20%20they%20fail&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihmpqE9ciDAxVjElkFHfpUCP4Q6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=invisible%20until%20%20they%20fail&f=false)

> As the sociologist and key reframing thinker Erving Goffman pointed
> out as far back as the 1960s, cultural norms are pretty much
> **invisible—right until you break them**.
> [Thomas Wedell-Wedellsborg; *What's Your Problem?*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vAiiDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT141&dq=I%20was%20invisible%20until%20i%20made%20trouble&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivr66A98iDAxUKD1kFHW-YCG0Q6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=I%20was%20invisible%20until%20i%20made%20trouble&f=false) (2020)

> In casual conversations with friends, colleagues, and even strangers,
> we found that "culture" and "identity" are **pervasive but invisible
> until they are pointed out**.
> [David Nunan and ‎Julie Choi (eds.); *Language
> and Culture*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sR2MAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA5&dq=%22invisible%20until%20%20they%20are%20pointed%20out%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidiMLQ-ciDAxWBEFkFHebTB6EQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22invisible%20until%20%20they%20are%20pointed%20out%22&f=false) (2010)

> Universally designed features tend to become **invisible until pointed
> out**, and therefore will become easier for others to imitate if well
> publicized.
> [Wolfgang F. E. Preiser, Jacqueline Vischer et al. (eds.);
> *Design Intervention*](https://books.google.com/books?id=u6FhCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT417&dq=%22invisible%20until%20pointed%20out%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj50Yme-siDAxXsD1kFHc3TAwYQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=%22invisible%20until%20pointed%20out%22&f=false) (2015)